# Microsoft SQL make sure user Id is the same across two tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, t-sql

I want to make the field/variable in one of my tables transfer across to another table. the variables is the user id of the current user. There is a relationship between the two tables. When a user registers for an account a UserId is made for them. I then want the user to be able to store other details about themselves(stored in a different table). These items should be linked to the user is. How do I get the UserId of the current user to become attached to the details they submit to the other table? These are the self-generated SQL commands Visual Studio made for me:

```
 SelectCommand="SELECT [Bhousenum], [Bstreetname], [Bcity], [Bcounty], [Bcountry], [Dhousenum], [Dstreetname], [Dcity], [Dcounty], [Dcountry], [Dpostcode], [Bpostcode], [mobilenum], [credittype], [creditname], [creditnum], [securitycode], [creditexpiry], [dob], [UserId] FROM [Customers] WHERE ([UserId] = @UserId)" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Customers] WHERE [UserId] = @UserId" 
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Customers] ([Bhousenum], [Bstreetname], [Bcity], [Bcounty], [Bcountry], [Dhousenum], [Dstreetname], [Dcity], [Dcounty], [Dcountry], [Dpostcode], [Bpostcode], [mobilenum], [credittype], [creditname], [creditnum], [securitycode], [creditexpiry], [dob], [UserId]) VALUES (@Bhousenum, @Bstreetname, @Bcity, @Bcounty, @Bcountry, @Dhousenum, @Dstreetname, @Dcity, @Dcounty, @Dcountry, @Dpostcode, @Bpostcode, @mobilenum, @credittype, @creditname, @creditnum, @securitycode, @creditexpiry, @dob, @UserId) WHERE [UserId] = @UserId" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Customers] SET [Bhousenum] = @Bhousenum, [Bstreetname] = @Bstreetname, [Bcity] = @Bcity, [Bcounty] = @Bcounty, [Bcountry] = @Bcountry, [Dhousenum] = @Dhousenum, [Dstreetname] = @Dstreetname, [Dcity] = @Dcity, [Dcounty] = @Dcounty, [Dcountry] = @Dcountry, [Dpostcode] = @Dpostcode, [Bpostcode] = @Bpostcode, [mobilenum] = @mobilenum, [credittype] = @credittype, [creditname] = @creditname, [creditnum] = @creditnum, [securitycode] = @securitycode, [creditexpiry] = @creditexpiry, [dob] = @dob WHERE [UserId] = @UserId">
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key - Have a read at this and it should start to fall into place :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a foreign key constraint when designing the associated table, see for example:

w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Answer (score 1):

What i understand from question is that you want to use the ID in your futher queries when the user is created if that is the case then you have to use the following output parameter in your user insert query

```
 SELECT @NewUserID = SCOPE_IDENTITY() // this commands return newly added id
```

This line should be written at the end of the query.

how to achive this , if you are using sqldatasource in your code then

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ...>
   <InsertParameters>
     ........other parameters 
   <asp:Parameter Direction="Output" Name="NewUserID " Type="Int32" />
  </InsertParameters> </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and if you want to use store procedure then you can write this as

```
  ALTE PROCEDURE dbo.Addusers(
     .....other parameters
    @NewProductID int OUTPUT
 )
```

and adding this ID into other tables you have to create foreign key in those tables. and use this ID to insert into those tables

foreign key adding command

```
  user_id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Userss(user_Id)
```

if you need any futher infor about this let me know

Answer (score 0):

Use "Output" parameter with Stored procedure. When you insert details send your user id back to front end then use this id to do other transactions.

for example:

```
create proc <procedure name>
(
  @name varchar(max),
  @OutUserID int output
)
as
begin
   insert into <table name> values (<your values>)
   set @OutUserID=scope_identity() 
end
```

this SP will get you an user id that has been inserted, but remember "scope_identity" only works after insert statement and your auto increment of primary key must be on.

Also you can use more than one output parameters.